# How to position header, sidebox and mainbox?

Tags: css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zz1ou0bv/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="sidebox">sidebox</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: red;
    height:60px;
}

.sidebox {
    width: 210px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

1. How do I position the blue box just under the red box? I could for example add `top: 68px;` to the `.sidebox` to fix the problem but is there any other way to position it automatically, I would like to change the header height without being forced to change the top tag in sidebox to make it fit.
2. How do I position a brand new div that takes up the WHOLE white area under the red box and besides blue box? This should be automatic in case header/sidebox changes height/width. The green content should be replaced with this new div: http://i.gyazo.com/a41107cb7c1844b439f045ad85d40aec.png

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the sidebar to occupy 100% of the window you could try this approach:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
.header {
    background-color: red;
    height:60px;
}

.sidebox {
    width: 210px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zz1ou0bv/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/rL8z9bm0/ .
Regarding your second question you should always have some kind of relation between the blue and yellow boxes, either pixels or percentage (better)

```
.sidebox {
    width: 30%;
    ...
}

.content {
    left:30%;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good use case for the `flexbox` here:

## [Fiddle with Flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/zz1ou0bv/4/)

Here's the relevant source:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="sidebox">sidebox</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    background-color: red;
    height:60px;
    flex: 1 100%;
}

.sidebox {
    flex: 1 auto;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
.content {
    flex: 4 auto;
    background-color: sienna;
    color: white;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How well do all of the different browsers support this implementation(vh, flex)?

Comment: Both are fairly well supported.  IE 10+, and all modern browsers.